# How do I refresh the legend of amChart after update and prevent duplication of legend

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am working with the free version of amChart, before thinking about
making a purchase I want to try it out and create specific interactions with the chart.

I succesfully made the chart update new data through a ajax call.
There are a couple of issues when I update the chart:

- The legend does not fully update with new data, I still see the labels of default setting
- The legend appears twice

```js
am4core.ready(function() {

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

// Create chart instance
let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
 chart.data = [{
 "2015": 0,
 "date": 'Jan'
 }, {
 "2015": 10,
 "date": 'Feb'
 }, {
 "2015": 0,
 "date": 'Mrt'
 }, {
 "2015": 10,
 "date": 'Apr'
 }];

//chart.data = <?= $test_array_json ?>;

// Create axes
let dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
dateAxis.dataFields.category = "date";

let valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();

// Create series
function createSeries(field, name) {

let series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = field;

series.dataFields.categoryX = "date";
series.name = name;
// series.tooltipText.disabled = true;
series.strokeWidth = 2;

let bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
bullet.circle.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;

return series;
}

// let series1 = createSeries("2019", "Series#2019");
// let series2 = createSeries("2020", "Series#2020");
// let series3 = createSeries("2021", "Series#2021");

console.log("chart.length[0]",Object.keys(chart.data[0]));

let count_serie = Object.keys(chart.data[0]);

count_serie.pop();

console.log("count_serie",count_serie);

for(let i = 0; i < count_serie.length; i++ ) {
let serie_val = "value" + i;
let serie_name = count_serie[i];

// console.log("length serie prop", count_serie.length);
// console.log("Series#", serie_name);
// console.log("Series#", serie_val);

let serie = createSeries(serie_name, serie_name);
}

chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();

$("#am_chart_query_selection").on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
url: '/xxx/xxxxxx/ajax/amChart.ajax.php', //?start='+start_date+'&end='+end_date,
method: "GET",
data: items,
dataType: "JSON",
success: function(response){
console.log("stringify", JSON.stringify(response));
console.log("regular", response);
// collect dates

//chart.data = response;

chart.data = [{
 "2017": 450,
 "2018": 362,
 "2019": 410,
 "date": 'Jan'
 }, {
 "2017": 455,
 "2018": 365,
 "2019": 415,
 "date": 'Feb'
 }, {
 "2017": 450,
 "2018": 362,
 "2019": 425,
 "date": 'Mrt'
 }, {
 "2017": 450,
 "2018": 362,
 "2019": 435,
 "date": 'Apr'
 }];

function createSeries(field, name) {

let series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = field;

series.dataFields.categoryX = "date";
series.name = name;
// series.tooltipText.disabled = true;
series.strokeWidth = 2;

let bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
bullet.circle.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;

return series;
}

let count_serie = Object.keys(chart.data[0]);

count_serie.pop();

console.log("count_serie",count_serie);

for(let i = 0; i < count_serie.length; i++ ) {
let serie_val = "value" + i;
let serie_name = count_serie[i];

// console.log("length serie prop", count_serie.length);
// console.log("Series#", serie_name);
// console.log("Series#", serie_val);

let serie = createSeries(serie_name, serie_name);
}
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

chart.legend.invalidate();

},
error: function (e) {
alert('Something went wrong with uploading the data');
console.log("Unsuccessful:", e);
}
});
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div>
<h2>amChart update</h2>
<form action="" method="get" id="am_chart_query_selection">
<label for="date_from">Search period:</label>
<input type="date" id="date_from" name="date_from">

<label for="date_untill"> t/m </label>
<input type="date" id="date_untill" name="date_untill">

<button id="submit" name="submit" value="search">search</button>
</form>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can refer below link: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/dynamically-adding-and-removing-series/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jQuery is not defined, you need to add the jQuery CDN before you call your chart code so

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

before you call

```
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
```